# How can I get Bootstrap 4 cols to be hortizontal in certain screen sizes?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

See image below for the layouts I'm trying to get in different screen sizes wit Bootstrap 4. At 768px and wider, the sidebar widgets are on the right. Narrower than 576px, the widgets stack like standard Bootstrap 4. But in between 576px and 769px, what combination of `col` sizes or ordering can I use to get the widgets to be side by side?

```css
.widget {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.widget3 {
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  height: 500px; // fixed height only for this demo
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid col-lg-10">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12">
      <div class="content">Content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
      <div class="widget">Widget 1</div>
      <div class="widget">Widget 2</div>
      <div class="widget3">Widget 3</div>
      <div class="widget">Widget 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

Comment: At first glance, this should be easy to do with [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try this

## [DEMO](https://www.codeply.com/p/haNjNAzQQH)

```
<div class="container py-2">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12"> Content </div>
    <div class="col-md-3  col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12  col-sm-6"> Widget1 </div>
            <div class="col-md-12  col-sm-6"> Widget2 </div>
            <div class="col-md-12  col-sm-6"> Widget3 </div>
            <div class="col-md-12  col-sm-6"> Widget4 </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```